# How export Properties from application context?

Tags: java, spring, properties, applicationcontext

There is needed to get several properties from spring application context and pack them into `java.util.Properties`. Is there a better way then do it by hand?

Something like:

```
@SomePropertyAnnotation("user", "host", "password")
private Properties userHostPassword;
```

Comment: How about autowiring ApplicationContext in your working class and retrieve what ever you wanted and play with it? Correct me, if i am wrong.

Comment: Are you using java/annotation configuration for Spring?